# cPanel Cron Job Run PHP File

Tags: cron, cpanel

I am trying to get my cronjob to work in cPanel.

I want to run the PHP file located at `http://www.mydomain.com/path/cron-job.php`
But it have to include `?code=something`

So it would be this: `http://www.mydomain.com/path/cron-job.php?code=something`

I tried using the following commands:
`php -q /home/mydomain/public_html/path/cron-jpb.php?code=something >/dev/null`
and
`/usr/bin/php -q /home/mydomain/public_html/path/cron-jpb.php?code=something >/dev/null`

But all without luck.. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the cron job is being run from the command line instead of via a Web server the GET portion is not being passed into your script. Try [this script](http://www.noah.org/wiki/PHP_CLI_GET) to pull the variables into the script from the CLI. I did not write that script, use at your own risk.